# How to convert Pandas dataframe to Numpy array without using extra memory

Tags: python, pandas

I am running a script on cloud, the cloud has a limit of 16GB Ram. So, I get error that I have exceeded the limit, when I run this line

```
train = np.array(train)
```

Comment: I think you can do train.values ? Assuming train is a dataframe

Comment: Do you mean I fit train dataframe in my ML model? I tried, but it even use more memory.

Comment: I mean you can access the underlying numpy array by querying the values method of a dataframe

Comment: Short story is you can't; just pass it as-is.